# Convert htaccess to nginx rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

.htaccess to nginx rewrite convertion help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a working PHP implementation, try:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/c-(.*)$ /catpost.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/a-(.*)-(.*)$ /archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

The main thing to remember is that `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`.

The first two rewrites may be inside the `location` block or not - depending on what other `location` blocks you have. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

The conditional rewrite is basically what `try_files` is designed to do. We use a named location to lose the leading `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.