# Converting htaccess rewrite to nginx rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm moving an application from Apache to nginx and I am stuck with the rewrite portion.

In my Apache .htaccess I have this. Basically, sends everything including query var to my index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Inside index.php I have a very basic section which breaks it down so I can route the visitor to where they need to go and also handle query var

```
if ( isset( $_GET['p'] ) ) {
    $page = explode( '/', $_GET['p'] );
} else {
    $page = NULL;
}
```

And later in the script

```
if ( $page ) {
    } if ( $page[0] == "stream" ) {
        if ( isset( $page[1] ) ) {
            // Blah
        }
    }
}
```

Also in various theme PHP files, I have am grabbing the URL vars with `$_GET['id']` or `$_GET['code']` to do various functions.

e.g. `http://example.com/verify?code=blah`

This URI comes into index.php, verify is found to be a theme file called `verify.php` and within `verify.php` it grabs the code url var.

I'm looking to replicate this with nginx and am getting stuck. I've tried the below:

```
        location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                rewrite ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 last;
#               try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$args;
#               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?p=$query_string;
        }
```

I've even tried the [example from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779723/1177153), but still not working.

Here I've tried to apply it to my setup:

```
location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 last;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

The commented sections are my trial and error. Any insight on how to replicate the Apache to nginx format?

Comment: You can flag this as duplicate. At first that answer referenced didn't solve my problem, but in the end it did. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) website?

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, it wants me to download the page instead of loading the page. For example if I go to http://example.com/about it wants me to download `about`. If I download it, the contents are my raw php `index.php` file

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but the [answer referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779723/1177153) in my question actually was the right answer. I'm hoping this will help someone in future.

I was a little too eager to try that answer and it failed as per the snippet above because I put my rewrite in twice. The working solution was to just put my rewrite only in the rewrite location.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
    }
```

This has (so far) successfully worked. It rewrites the URL to the specific php theme page, and the theme pages have access to the query vars.